# How to add erorr bars on barcharts in ggplot that has already been calculated?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the standard error in my bar charts but I already calculated my standard error and its in one of the columns of my dataset? Is there a way to do this without using geombar since geombar asks for the min and max.

I just want to be able to plot the value of my standard error using the column that I already calculated for standard error. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a little of a) the code you've tried so far and b) a sample of data to work with so we know we're suggesting things that fit your data? You can create a pastable data-constructor using `dput` or generate some data with the right column names to experiment with.

Comment: See [the help for `geom_errorbar`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_linerange.html) and the examples on that page.